# uenvcmd in uEnv.txt can not be executed automatically

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, bootloader, u-boot

I am using an arm board using TFTP and NFS but it got stuck at kernel loading as shown in the screenshot and I have to input the `run uenvcmd` then the process will keep going and everything is OK.
[image: screenshot]

Below is my uEnv.txt:

```
# This uEnv.txt file can contain additional environment settings that you
# want to set in U-Boot at boot time.  This can be simple variables such
# as the serverip or custom variables.  The format of this file is:
#    variable=value
# NOTE: This file will be evaluated after the bootcmd is run and the
#       bootcmd must be set to load this file if it exists (this is the
#       default on all newer U-Boot images.  This also means that some
#       variables such as bootdelay cannot be changed by this file since
#       it is not evaluated until the bootcmd is run.
autoload=no
ipaddr=192.168.1.100
serverip=192.168.1.13
gatewayip=192.168.1.1
staticip=${ipaddr}:${serverip}:${gatewayip}:255.255.255.0:::off
bootpath=/tftpboot
rootfspath=/opt/ti-processor-sdk-linux-rt-am57xx-evm-03.00.00.04/targetNFS

#setting for kernel loading
kernel_addr=0x82000000
fdt_addr=0x88000000

nfs_args=setenv bootargs console=ttyO0,115200n8 root=/dev/nfs rw nfsroot=${serverip}:${rootfspath} ip=${staticip}
load_zimage=tftp ${kernel_addr} ${bootpath}/zImage
loadfdt=tftp ${fdt_addr} ${bootpath}/am572x-idk.dtb
boot_zimage=bootz ${kernel_addr} - ${fdt_addr}
uenvcmd=run load_zimage; run loadfdt; run nfs_args; run boot_zimage
```

these is a strange file called `uboot.env` beside the `uEnv.txt`, too long to paste here, [uboot.env](http://pastebin.com/WTV4hSEd)

Comment: So, per the note, what's `bootcmd` (and anything else relevant) set to in your environment? Presumably that's what's trying to load the non-existent /boot/zImage. Also, post text as text; a screenshot of a text in a terminal which could have been trivially selected and copied is inexcusable.

Comment: `uenvcmd=run load_zimage; run loadfdt; run nfs_args; run boot_zimage` it's in my uEnv.txt

Comment: @Notlikethat because I want to highlight the input, I can not highlight the text without the image

Comment: `uenvcmd` is not `bootcmd`... Maybe just add the output of `printenv` to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: Just delete the file `uboot.env`
This should be a bug of SDK. I will report this to TI. Thanks @Notlikethat